# End of file unexpected in haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

I think I have researched very hard about my problem so here I am.

I have a "end of file unexpected" error at line 
6 colunm 33.

I have already tried many solutions to resolve my problem.

Here is my code and the file I am trying to parse.

Here is the text I am trying to parse :

**ifc.txt :**

```
#9512= IFCBUILDINGSTOREY('3y21AUC9X4yAqzLGUny16E',#16,'Story',$,$,#9509,$,$,.ELEMENT.,6200.);
#9509= IFCLOCALPLACEMENT(#115,#9506);
#9506= IFCAXIS2PLACEMENT3D(#9502,#9498,#9494);
#9502= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.,6200.));
#9498= IFCDIRECTION((0.,0.,1.));
#9494= IFCDIRECTION((1.,0.,0.));
```

Here is the code :

**code.hs :**

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
main = do
  f <- readFile "ifc.txt"
  let m = (parse ifc "" f)
  print m

ifc :: Parser IfcModel
ifc = many ifcentry

ifcentry = do
  string "#"
  i <- idt
  string "= "
  name <- idt
  string "("
  prop <- idt
  string ")"
  string ";"
  string "\n"
  return (i,name,prop)

idt = many (letter <|> digit <|> char ','
   <|> char '$' <|> char ')' <|> char '\''
   <|> char '=' <|> char ';'  <|> char '\n'
   <|> char ' ' <|> char '(' <|> char '#'
   <|> char '.' <|> char '\r')
```

Thanks for your help, i should have checked a bit earlier my anwser because i worked on my own and i found asolution i will post it when i can (8hours left for a newbie like me who has less than 10 in reputation).

Thanks again.

Comment: you know that haskell is indent sensitive? in addition your parser looks for the newline character in the last line and doesn't find it, I guess. On a side note - what is the definition of IfcModel?

Comment: and claiming that you have researched hard is not the same as doing it - what did you try?

Comment: Yes I know the indent problem i just posted this version because i am not used to the format stackoverflow. If you look at the chapter 16 of Haskell Real world, about their example you will see a example of are you they dealt with the end of line character on windows or linux. I tried it : [link](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) .

Comment: The problem is not the difference between line endings in Windows vs Unix; it is that you don't *have* a new line at the end of your file (and hence neither Unix nor Windows line end), but the parser expects one. Even if you add a new line to ifc.txt, you still probably need a condition in your parser to detect eof. Since the code you posted doesn't compile, it is hard to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone, i should have checked a bit earlier my anwser because i worked on my own and finally found a solution :

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

main = do
 f <- readFile "ifc.txt"
 let m = (parse ifc "" f)
 print m

type IfcIdt = String
type IfcName = String
type IfcProp = [String]
type IfcModel = [(IfcIdt,IfcName,IfcProp)]

ifc :: Parser IfcModel
ifc = many ifcentry

ifcentry = do
 string "#"
 i <- idtnumber
 string "= "
 name <- idtname
 opening
 prop <- ifcprop
 closing
 eol
 return (i,name,prop)

idtnumber = many digit
idtname = many (letter <|> digit)

ifcprop = sepBy prop (char ',')
prop = many (noneOf "=,();\n")
eol = string ";\n"
opening = try (string "((")
 <|> string "("
closing = try (string "))")
 <|> string ")"
```

Comment: Can I advise against `noneOf`; you're defining your parser based on what isn't allowed instead of what is. The chances of you forgetting something that shouldn't be in a `prop` are much higher than the chances of you forgetting something that should be in a `prop`.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution: use `sepBy` instead of including the newline in `ifcentry`

Your `ifcentry` expects a newline at the end, and your input doesn't have one, which is why the EOF was unexpected.

Drop the `string "\n"` from `ifcentry` and instead define

```
ifc :: Parser IfcModel
ifc = ifcentry `sepBy` (char '\n')
```

Also, your `idt` parser is needlessly long. It would be clearer as

```
idt = many (letter <|> digit <|> oneOf ".,;' =#$()\n\r")
```

### Clearer `ifcentry`

And while I'm at it, I'd write

```
ifcentry = do
  char '#'
  i <- idt
  string "= "
  name <- idt
  prop <- parens idt
  char ';'
  return (i,name,prop)
```

Because `parens` (which parses an open bracket, your `idt` content, then a close bracket) tidies it up and makes it clearer.

### Less verbose `main`

I'd also write

```
main = fmap (parse ifc "") (readFile "ifc.txt") >>= print
```

certainly there's no need for

```
  let m = (parse ifc "" f)
  print m
```

because you may as well do

```
  print (parse ifc "" f)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to @enough rep to comment's answer

I would go much further and declare something in the line of

```
data IFCType = IFCBuildingStorey ....
             | IFCLocalPlacement ....
             | IFCAxis2Placement3D ....
             | IFCCartesianpoint Double Double Double
             | IFCDirection ....
             deriving Show
```

and

```
type ID = Integer
type IFCElement = (ID,IFCType)
```

where i will show the CartesianPoint as an example

```
ifctype :: Parser IFCType
ifctype = do string "IFC"
             buildingStorey
             <|> localPlacement
             <|> axis2Placement3D
             <|> cartesianpoint
             <|> direction

buildingStorey :: Parser IFCType
buildingStorey = do string "BUILDINGSTOREY"
                    return IFCBuildingStorey

localPlacement :: Parser IFCType
localPlacement = do string "LOCALPLACEMENT"
                    return IFCLocalPlacement

axis2Placement3D :: Parser IFCType
axis2Placement3D = do string "AXIS2PLACEMENT3D"
                      return IFCAxis2Placement3D

cartesianpoint :: Parser IFCType
cartesianpoint = do string "CARTESIANPOINT"
                    char '('
                    char '('
                    x <- double
                    char ','
                    y <- double
                    char ','
                    z <- double
                    char ')'
                    char ')'
                    return $ IFCCartesianpoint x y z

double :: Parser Double
double = do d <- many1 (digit <|> char '.')
            return $ read d

direction :: Parser IFCType
direction = do string "DIRECTION"
               return IFCDirection
```

this has the additional advantage that you have typed models.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Algebraic data type is very much The Way To Go. I agree.

Comment: I had to hold back from importing `Control.Applicative` and doing like `cartesianpoint = string "CARTESIANPOINT" >> (parens.parens $ IFCCartesianpoint <$> double <* char ',' <*> double <* char ',' <*> double)`. There. I've said it. I feel better now. This comment should go under my answer really, but I didn't have an ADT to use.

Comment: can you tell me where `parens` is to be imported from? if I use the one from Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Tokens I get a type mismatch error